# Is there a way to replace all instances of .at() in my code with brackets, without altering the text inside

Tags: regex, xcode

Say I have a for loop and a vector.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
    vector.at(x) = 0;
}
```

Is there a way to replace .at(x), with [x], without changing the text inside? Also it would need to work with any arbitrary text. I think there should be a way to do this with regex, but I don't know how.

Comment: What if `x` is actually `someOtherVector.at(y)`? What if it's `myMap.at(y)`? Regex won't work with arbitrary text, but maybe your text is constrained enough and benign enough to be treatable with regex...

Comment: Something like this (using `sed` since I don't have xcode):  `sed -r 's/\.at\(([^)]+)\)/[\1]/g'` - but do check the result before saving. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use can try a sed based approach like below.  However, this will only work for straight-forward search/replace patterns.  If you think your code base may have more complex index expressions, e.g. something like `vector.at( foo().at(bar()) )` then this approach will get complex. It may introduce subtle and unwanted code changes -- ensure to diff the files before and after running the sed !

if had a file (code.cc) with line like this:

```
vector.at(xx) ;  vector.at(YY) ;
vector.at( i - j) ;  vector.at(KKK - _LLL) ;
```

doing:

```
cat file.cc |  sed -e 's!.at(\([^)]*\))![\1]!g'
```

gives

```
vector[xx] ;  vector[YY] ;
vector[ i - j] ;  vector[KKK - _LLL] ;
```

Note, this regexp will not work for more complex lookups, eg, vector.at( foo() )

Comment: Any reason for `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*` instead of `.*`?

Comment: want to match only variable names, and not greedily eat the entire line  (i.e. there could be two or more vector.at(..) on a single line

Comment: Good point! Thanks!

Comment: although its fair point ...  the thing inside the at(..) brackets could be more complex, eg,  `vector.at(i - j)`   .... this regex won't handle that

Comment: True, you just have to make sure that you wont end up with something like `vector[x) = 0; vector.at(y];` Maybe some trick using `;` could be more accurate. But then again imagine a map lookup where `';'` serves as a key...

Comment: yeah, this is more complex ... I think it needs to properly parse the code, eg, vector.at( foo().at(bar()) )   etc   ... and, the danger of running sed naively is that it might introduce subtle bugs.